# Finding source-like nodes in a flow notework

Tags: algorithms, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Let $G$ be a flow network, where $c(e)$ is the capacity of an edge, and the source is $s$ and sink $t$.  Define a node $v$ to be "source-like" if for every min-cut $(S,T)$ of $G$ where $S$ contains $s$, $S$ contains $v$.  Find an efficient algorithm to determine the source-like nodes.

I was thinking that since Ford-Fulkerson is efficient, we can go ahead and run that to get the max flow solution, and perhaps use that to find the source-like nodes.  However, as I look at examples and try to think of what to do with the flow network, I don't see how to identify source-like nodes.

Of course when you look at the residual graph at the end of Ford-Fulkerson, there is a cut where all the edges point away from $t$ and toward $s$ roughly speaking.  This cut is a min-cut.  But it is just one min-cut.  I'm not sure how to work in the idea of all possible min-cuts.  Cutting an edge seems like a bad idea.  Redirecting flow in small changes seems like a bad idea.

When I think of a graph where I can trivially spot two distinct min-cuts, I think of:

```
s -> b weight 3
s -> c weight 3
b -> d weight 3
c -> e weight 3 
d -> t weight 3
e -> t weight 3
```

Basically this just sets up two parallel tracks.  In fact as I think about it, here I think the source-like node would be the source node.

I wonder if it's the case that in any max-flow solution, every min-cut is some set of edges which are completely used up by the max-flow?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 1):

The example given in the question suggests that we want to find the min-cut that is "nearest" to the source $s$.

The answer is "the first" min-cut yielded by a max-flow. More specifically, find a max-flow $f$ of $G$, which can be done efficiently by Ford-Fulkerson algorithm or other algorithms. Let $G_f$ be the residual network of $f$. Let $S$ be the set of the nodes reachable from $s$ in $G_f$. Then $S$ is the set of all source-like nodes.